# Writing css background with PHP doesn't work?

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to set a background image for the images preview of a gallery and nothing is shown. I'm using:

```
echo '<div class="prev" style="background-image:url(' . $image . ')"></div>';
```

In addition the prev class is:

```
.prev {
    width:120px;
    height:90px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center; 
}
```

`$image` variable is ok, I echoed it for test, and when I put the same url (this echo) in a div not written by php, the image is shown perfectly.

Comment: just a minor  style="background-image:url(' . $image . ');" add the semicolon ;

Comment: Thanks! but doesn't work neither :(

Comment: Are there any special characters in the url?

Comment: Inspect with firebus or similar the real link for image ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was correct:

```
echo '<div class="prev" style="background-image:url(' . $image . ')"></div>';
```

Works perfectly, the problem was the folder name (from where I get the $image variable), this folder contains a space, and PHP glob function reads the directory with spaces perfectly, so when I echo it I get something like:

```
images/name containing space/any_image.jpg
```

But CSS needs the URL without these spaces, to work it needs to replace the spaces with %20.

Thanks all for your expertise!

Answer (score 1):

`url` needs to be between quotes

```
echo '<div class="prev" style="background-image:url(\'' '. $image . '\');"></div>';
```

Comment: But when I set the URL in CSS it works without quotes.... I tried your suggestion and result unfortunately is the same. Really weird.